# Green function of three band crossing topological material in energy coordinate representation do not converge

Tags: greens-functions, topological-insulators

Recently I am studying the properties of Green function of three diamentional topological materials with three band crossings, whose Hamiltonian can be written as $\hat H= v_f \ \vec k \cdot \vec S $, here $\vec S$ denote the angular momentum operator with quantum number $1$. Here its eigen values are $\epsilon_ {\pm}=\pm v_f k $ and $\epsilon_ {0}=0$.

For the green function of the flat band namely the one with eigen value $\epsilon_ {0}=0$, it can be written as $$\frac{I-\frac{(\vec k \cdot \vec S)^2}{k^2}}{\epsilon+i0^{+}}$$. Here $I$ is the $3 \times 3$ unit matrix. When Fourier transforming the Green Function from energy-momentum representation to energy-coordinate representation, the first term, namely $$\frac{1}{(2\pi)}\int dk^3\frac{I}{\epsilon+i0^{+}}e^{ikr}=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int^\infty_0 dk  \frac {k}{r}sin(kr)$$ apprently do not converge. I am wondering whether it's because the eigen state for the flat band is not localized, or I can just treat this term as zero?